# Clients cannot connect to internet | windows server 2003 is allocating DHCPs

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server 2003 which gives DHCPs to all other devices. I am using TP-Link MR 3220 as the WIFI-Router.

The problem is that after 20 devices are connected to the Internet and the server, I cannot connect my other devices to the internet nor to the server through WIFI.

But when I try to connect through a LAN port whether of the WIFI Router or through LAN switched available, the server gives my device a new DHCP lease and things work fine.

Comment: Have you checked the router's settings?

Comment: Yes, I had disabled the DHCP from router's side and there are no MAC addresses or any other IP addresses banned. The scope of address lease is also from 192.168.0.1 to 199 from the windows 2003 server.
Is there anything else I should be checking?

Answer (score 0):

Windows and your wifi router may not be the problem. What are the limitations of the actual 3g/4g device giving your wifi router internet?